# how to get the values of integers A,B and C that give the closest value to N?

Tags: optimization

I have this formula : $N = 3 \cdot A \cdot B \cdot C + 4 \cdot A \cdot B + 4 
\cdot A + 1$, where A B and C are integers that belong to the range $[0, 255]$

how can I choose the values of A,B,C in order to get a value of N that is close to a given number ?

for example, if N should be $\approx 10^6$, we would choose
A=$46$, B=$189$ and C = $37$
resulting in N = $999,995$